# How do you create either a geotiff or a .tfw in QGIS using python?

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, print-composer

Probably I just don't understand the API documentation, I don't use object oriented programming to its full capability.

I do see this has to be done from a composer object in order to automatically apply the on-the-fly projection transformations since the input layers have different CRSs.  (Right?)

I found the c++ code that generates the worldfile, but, how do you generate the worldfile from the python console?

More generally, how do you export from a composer to geotiff (or, alternately, write a .tfw worldfile) using python?